# Previous focused control in WinForms

Tags: winforms, focus

I have a win form with lot of controls:
[image]

I want to know when user enters 'txt2' exactly after he entered 'txt1'. In other words when user is in 'txt2' I want to know was previous control 'txt1' or not.

What is the best way to such thing?

Comment: Can you specify in which language you are working? My answer assumed that you are working in .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just keep a module-level variable of the type Control that stores the last control to receive focus. Since you need to keep track of each control which receives focus, each control needs to subscribe to a common event handler for the Enter event. In that event you will assign the control that has been entered to the module-level variable, but before that you can test for the jump between 'txt1' and 'txt2'.

Comment: Does this mean that I must add Enter event handler to every control om my form?

Comment: You can have one common Enter event handler for multiple controls. Do you want the same all controls to have a similar awareness as that between 'txt1' and 'txt2'?

Comment: In that case only 'txt2' has to have an event handler for the Enter event.

Comment: But if I select some other control after 'txt1' and after that 'txt2': txt1 - > OTHER -> txt2, this local variable will tell me that last control was txt1 what is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will edit my answer to take this into account.